# Tkinter StringVar to uppercase

Tags: python, tkinter

I get the user entry as a StringVar from an Entry box but would like to convert it to uppercase.
I then use the variable in another routine. I have been unable to find the syntax to simply convert 'c6h12' to 'C6H12' when its in a StringVar.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show us your complete code?

Comment: `the_var.get().upper()` will get the value and convert it to uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet does the trick, simply using the StringVar `get()` method to get the old value, and `set()` method to update the value after calling `upper()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

sv = StringVar(value="c6h12")
sv.set(sv.get().upper())

root.mainloop()
```